# Configure a "hardened" user account that an attacker would have a hard time abusing

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2

Suppose you have a Windows Server machine running various sensitive services. Suppose that one of these services is pretty simple, maintaining a small amount of information in a text file, but as a result of being badly coded, has an (unknown) arbitrary code execution vulnerability.

Is it possible to set up a user account for that service such that if a hacker were to exploit this vulnerability successfully, the most damage they could do is read/write this text file, mess up this specific service, and possibly list the files out of C:\Windows, but nothing else?

A naive attempt at doing this immediately runs into a problem: anyone in "Users" can write to C:\Program Files, and removing "Users" from that directory's ACL results in a permission error, making me wonder if, perhaps, it is a very bad idea.

Or is the game already lost if the attacker can execute arbitrary code, regardless of which user account is used? I've always thought Windows NT descendants make it possible to contain this, but now that I've tried, I'm no longer so sure.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is harden (including your policies for handling anything on) the host itself.

Comment: I trust the users who log on legitimately. It's not super-sensitive stuff.

Comment: @romkyns - have you not heard of buffer overflow attacks? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, users can *not* write to `C:\Program Files`. They have Read, List Folder Contents, and Read & Execute. If that's not the case with you, then someone or something has modified those permissions.

A limited user can read much of the filesystem, but can only write to locations that it has explicitly been given access to, like its user profile.

If you grant Modify *only* to that one text file, the only thing that account will be able to write to on the filesystem is that file, plus things in its profile directory (My Documents, etc) which should be of no consequence.

If you have the built-in Users group having modify permissions all over your filesystem, then this is non-standard. Out of the box, limited user accounts can do very little damage.

By itself an arbitrary code execution bug is not especially harmless if the service account running its process is limited in privilege. The problem is that there are *so many* privilege escalation exploits out there that once you can arbitrarily execute code, you can just execute something that will allow you to break out of your privilege level. By itself, arbitrary code execution isn't a big deal, but in the real world it's almost always bundled with a privilege escalation exploit. So, yes, I'd be concerned.

Comment: You're right, the "Users" group does not have write access to Program Files. I'd still much rather prefer if the limited user could only read the locations it really has to be able to read, rather than having access to most of the disk.

Comment: @romkyns Same here. I'm still looking for a concrete solution. What was yours, if I may ask?

Comment: @dimitko I set up all sensitive data on a separate volume D:\, and removed the "Users" group from the ACL for the volume root. I then gave the service accounts access just to those parts of D: that they required. I left C:\ alone, so all service accounts have default access rights there. I don't consider this bullet-proof, just a part of "defense in depth".

Answer (score 4):

Some quite interesting answers here.

Taking an empirical stance, with numerous post-penetration test "things to fix lists" under my belt, I would actually say that Microsoft have done a great job in recent years of providing the tools and options to harden a server very well.

Of course, MS still fuzz their code, and they and the community continue to find remote execution / privilege escalation exploits, but I've got to say, their patching is on-the-ball compared to some other vendors (SonicWall, Tivoli and Oracle spring to mind).

My recommendations would be:

- Make sure User Account Control (UAC) is enabled
- Ensure Data Execution Prevention (DEP) is enabled
- Use managed service accounts (Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2 and above)
- Start with the absolute minimum privileges, and only add more if absolutely required.  I mean file system privs and User Rights Assignment (Local Security Policy or Group Policy)
- Use Microsoft's Process Monitor to diagnose privilege issues (when experimenting ^^^)
- Make sure the server is patched (Security patches at least, via WSUS)
- If you have 3rd party software installed, keep that patched too.
- Uninstall Java.  Unless you *really* need it.  Patch it.  Then patch it again 'cause the patch you applied didn't fix the fault that Oracle said it would.  Sorry, Oracle have ruined Sun Java!
- Keep your hardware vendor's systems software up-to-date (BIOS, device drivers, Etc.)
- Use Windows auditing to monitor activity of your new shiny account.
- Forward events somewhere central.
- Examine forwarded events daily or at least configure triggers to alert where necessary.
- Enable the Windows Firewall (it's a shame, but so many people turn it off)
- Ensure your server is backed up, so if the worst happens, you have your data.
- Develop a plan for what you would do if the worst did happen.
- Don't allow your server access to the Internet.  Again, I can't believe the number of data centres I've been to where there is open HTTP(S) access to the Internet for all servers.  Some people need to be taken aside for a chat.

It's important to remember, there is no such thing as a completely secure o/s, application or network.  It's all about layers of prevention, and identifying when things look different.  Don't get sold on Intrusion Detection either, unless of course, you a) are susceptible to hyped up sales pitches, b) have lots of free time on your hands and c) have plenty of spare $$$.

Finally, the most devious "attacks" these days aren't about disruption; quite the opposite.  The focus (and funding!) has switched to data exfiltration.

Comment: as a general principle then, is it wise to disable internet access for a server, even if the perimeter firewall won't allow any connections in to that server?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  Should the server be infected by a worm, (however unlikely) outbound access allows a reverse-proxy style command and control (C&C) channel to be established.  Essentially, your server can be controlled using response packets.  Also, unfettered outbound HTTP is an easy way to exfiltrate data.  Neither of these are theoretical risks.

Answer (score 2):

In the Linux world, [we would use SELinux](https://serverfault.com/a/415332/126632) or another [mandatory access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) mechanism to mitigate this sort of threat.

Windows doesn't have anything quite so robust, but since Vista/2008 it does have a basic [integrity mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Integrity_Control) which you might be able to use. (Though, this has a [rather high learning curve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625964.aspx) and explaining it fully would require more length than is permitted here.)

I think your best short-term mitigation would be to isolate the service in a virtual machine.

Comment: +1 For mentioning `SELinux`

Answer (score 2):

If "execute arbitrary code" means the process can create directories, it may be possible for them to create directories either in the current directory, the service account's user profile directory, the root of the C:\ drive, or simply search for a directory where it can create directories.

Last time I checked, Windows usually conferred the permission to create directories in the root of C:.  You may not see this in the gui due to you would need to view the Advanced property page or use ICACLS to get a complete list of permissions.

Even if the C:\ root directory permission had been hardened, it is trivial to search all directories on C:\ and test for one where permissions allow the service account to create directories.  Chances are there will be one.

If the process exploit can create directories somewhere on C:, then it is fairly straightforward to disable the system by creating millions or billions of empty directories/subdirectories.

Empty directories are zero bytes, so are not subject to quotas.  These directories are also stored directly in the MFT (due to their small size), so even if the process could be stopped and the directories deleted, the MFT is effectively trashed - so large and/or fragmented that the system may need to be restored from backup.

Answer (score 1):

Use DEP for all processes. It'll stop a majority, but there are a lot of exploits that can defeat DEP anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Preventing abuse has to be done from the ground up - no point doing it to an account on an insecure server with a large attack surface

So;

1) Make sure the server is patched.

2) You can use SCW (Security Config Wizard) to harden the server.  It will do a faster and better job than most admins will do.

It allows you do undo the changes made, but it will only undo one-step.  So if you run it, lock stuff down and then run it again (i.e. if you missed something) and *then* you notice something is broken, if it broke that during the first lock down, you can't easily undo it (have to do it manually)

So, after running it and applying it, **test functionality thoroughly**.

3) *Then*, make sure you are using accounts which aren't admins, power-users etc and that they have only NTFS permissions to do the bare minimum of what they need to do - nothing else.

4) You can also use local security policy (or domain policy, if server is a domain member) to lock down other aspects of the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly try to create a secure user similar to the ones that come with windows that can't be logged into, and only have access to a certain files on the machine.  The con is that a privilege escalation exploit could work on that user depending on the situation.

With linux we chroot jail processes and services like this as *part* of a security mitigation strategy.  I'm not a Windows guy, but how would you do this in Windows?

One thing you could do to put the service in a sandbox is run it in a VM.  [Virtualbox](http://virtualbox.org) is my choice since you could even install it on the same box if you wanted to and make it start with the server, even headless, so it would almost run just like a service. It's free also. It's very difficult for an exploit to escape your VM.  The con to this approach is that you would run another whole instance of windows, which would itself need to be kept up to date and would consume resources.

Another thing that would work is using a dedicated sandbox program such as [sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) that can sandbox any process to make it harder to escape if it gets compromised.